# mySQL lock records from cronjobs

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores customer submitted forms.

There is also a cron script that selects records from this table for processing. It runs every minute.

`SELECT * from Forms where to_CRM = 0 limit 10`

The problem is sometimes the API takes a while to complete so that sometimes the next batch is already requested to run before the previous batch completes.

This causes the same person to be selected for processing as his `To_CRM` flag is still 0;

It is imperative that a lock does not lock the table from being able to insert new records.

What is the best way to solve this issue via transactions or a different approach like setting a column in the table while it's processing?

Comment: I'd handle this by preventing the cron from running more than once at a time - perhaps by checking for and `touch()`ing a lock file when starting, then `unlink()`ing it when complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to actually update the table:

```
UPDATE Forms SET to_CRM=1499358596 WHERE to_CRM=0 LIMIT 10
```

Where that represents the time of execution. Then:

```
SELECT * From Forms WHERE to_CRM=1499358596
```

This won't double up because each run will exclude those that it's operating on from subsequent runs due to the `WHERE` clause. I'm presuming you can use the `to_CRM` field here, but you could just as well add another specifically for locking/claiming.

Comment: That is what I was initially thinking, i was just wondering if a transaction would accomplish the same ends.

Comment: A transaction won't help you here because your `SELECT` doesn't modify anything. You need to write in order for two processes to coordinate. You would use a transaction to rescue from when your process crashes to release these updates and any incomplete writes. That may end up blocking other workers depending on how you implement it, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Right but I would always write at the end of the transaction to change the to_CRM flag on the record

Comment: The first thing you do is manipulate that value and closing the transaction successfully would commit the change permanently. A `ROLLBACK` would undo it, allowing another instance of the worker to process it later.